# GET api not working in react native but same api works with other tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, axios

I have a weird problem with a third party API. I am trying to perform a `GET` operation of the API, but it throws a `403 error` in react-native but the same `GET` API works with Postman, web browser console. I couldn't resolve this issue.

I have tried to add `credentials: true`, `user-agent same as a web browser`, but nothing works.

The code is :

```js
axios.get(`https://api.thirdparty.org/username/file/src`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "token"
        } 
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        return {
            status: 200,
            data: response.data
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response)
        return {
            status: 400,
            message: 'Incorrect details'
        }
    })
```

This is the Postman header for the `GET` api
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried it with fetch API....Does it works then

Comment: Can I see the postman sent?

Comment: Check with the backend you are accessing with the right expected `Authorization`. Many times backends expect `Authorization` to come with the string `Bearer` as `"Bearer ${your_token}"`, but it doesn't have to be your case.

Comment: If it were bad authorization, you'd expect `Error 401: "The request requires user authentication.` rather than `Error 403: "The server understood the request, but is refusing to authorize it."` - too bad the back-end isn't IIS - which gives "substatus" error codes to further pinpoint the problem

Comment: @kunalverma I tried `fetch` but no luck

Comment: @Dez Yes. I have set the right `Authorization` but still, it's not working

Comment: To be able to compare the two calls with each other, we need to see exactly what was sent in both cases. Please post a screenshot of what was actually sent by your javascript (from a network tab, or Fiddler, or something).

Answer (score 0):

**using try and catch**

The throw statement lets you create custom errors.

Technically you can throw an exception (throw an error).

```js
getApiData = async () =>{
    try {
        const url =  "https://api.thirdparty.org/username/file/src";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if(response.status !== 200){
            throw("bad request");
        }
        const result = await response.json();
        return result;
    } catch(err){
        throw(err)
    }
}
```